# Couldnt figure it out from this youtube video

Tags: texas-hold-em

I was watching this video and couldnt figure out why the losing guy was hoping for he board to be paired. Could anyone enlighten me? I am confused

https://youtu.be/q7xtKdX9LFo?t=22m28s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a full house on the river to beat the straight Nguyen needs to get either two pair or trips on the turn. On this board a king, jack or a nine will give him that. He can also hit a seven, but since that is relatively unlikely he calls for a boardpair.